# Colocar un bloque al lado de otro con css

Tags: html5, css3, web

El siguiente código simula al original

```css
.padre{
    border: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
 <div class="padre">
       <div>
          <h2> HIJO 1 CON TEXTO</h2>
          <p> texto muy largo pero muy muy largo <p>
       </div>
       <div>
          <h2> HIJO 2 CON TEXTO MAS COOL </h2>
          <p> otro texto muy largo pero muy muy largo <p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

El problema que tengo es que, si bien mis cuadros quedan uno al lado del otro, los textos no quedan parejos verticalmente. 
Aparte los marcos de los dos cuadro en el centro quedan muy pegados. 
**¿Cómo podría separarlos sin que el margen de la página quede desparejo?**

Comment: Hola Gilberto. Podrías añadir el código completo de tu css , el código que "simula al original" no expresa la duda que tienes en tu código.

Comment: Te falta añadir el código CSS de los hijos para ver cómo los estás poniendo uno al lado del otro

Comment: Yo si lo pongo en grande me aparece un cuadro encima del otro, no uno al lado del otro. ¿Es así como se tendrían que ver?

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar alguna imagen de cómo sale y cómo debería quedar?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no se puede reproducir el problema

Answer (score 1):

Probá esto:

```
.padre{
   border: 1px;
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: left;
}
```

Lo que hice fue modificar el alineamiento del texto y los márgenes atomáticos.

Answer (score 1):

Propongo que hagas un texto justificado y al div le pongas un padding interior que reduce el espacio dentro.

```
.padre{
    border: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px, 20px;
    text-align: justify;
}
```